# How to display foreign characters?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I just downloaded brackets after hearing that it will probably be the next big editor. I know it is still in beta, but does anyone know how to display foreign characters in this editor? When I try to display a foreign character, this symbol � is displayed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Brackets currently only supports UTF-8 encoded files.

There's an item in the feature backlog to [support other encodings](https://trello.com/c/DShzQztM/731-support-non-utf-8-encodings), so you should upvote it if that's an important use case for you.

If you're pretty certain that the file you're working with *is* UTF-8 encoded (bearing in mind that it's tricky to tell for sure), then it sounds like you've hit a bug. As a Brackets core contributor, I definitely encourage you to [file it in our issue tracker](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/new) — and please include a link to the file in question if at all possible.